# Custom adapter for ListView ignores set values

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-listadapter

I'm going to create a `ListView` of labels and icons.

Here's what I've done:

I've created a blank `ListView` called `cardList`.

I've created a custom view that extends `ArrayAdapter<String>`

And I've set the `cardList` to that custom view:

```
cardList = findViewById(R.id.cards_list);
CustomView customView = new CustomView(this, names, images);
cardList.setAdapter(customView);
```

where

```
ListView cardList;
String[] names = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"};
Integer[] images = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3};
```

The `CustomView` class:

```
package ...

import ...

public class CustomView extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private String[] names;
    private Integer[] images;
    private Activity context;

    CustomView(Activity context, String[] names, Integer[] images) {
        super(context, R.layout.card_row, R.id.cardName, names);
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
        this.images = images;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View r = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (r == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            r = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_row, null, true);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(r);
            r.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) r.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.name.setText(/*skipping: names[position]*/"Some text");
        viewHolder.name.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(AppName.assetManager, "fonts/prototype.ttf"));
        viewHolder.image.setImageResource(images[position]);
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        ImageView image;
        ViewHolder(View v) {
            name = v.findViewById(R.id.cardName);
            image = v.findViewById(R.id.symbolImg);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, on purpose I wrote the line `viewHolder.name.setText(/*skipping: names[position]*/"Some text");` like this. The result is that my `ListView` is displayed with names from the array although the method `setText("Some text")` should change that, and there are no icons and custom font. So, the problem is with this section:

```
viewHolder.name.setText(/*skipping: names[position]*/"Some text");
viewHolder.name.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(AppName.assetManager, "fonts/prototype.ttf"));
viewHolder.image.setImageResource(images[position]);
```

Debugging has shown that the application goes through this section, but all the things that should be set inside of it are ignored. Am I missing something?

Comment: use recyclerview instead of listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom view is ignored as you return parent view from `getView` instead of your one

Use

```
return r;
```

Instead of

```
return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

Comment: What a silly mistake I made... I'm too inattentive. Thank you, anyway!

Comment: @Xander402, You are wlcome.